# defining multiple variabless within a form issue

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Hi guys I have something that I do not know how to make it work. 
I am working on a questionnaire like, where on a page will show up the questionn and a radio like form list of answers that the user can select.

I gave it a try but I do not know how to link a question to my form, could you please help ?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Questionnaire(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=600)
    multiple_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question

class Answers(models.Model):
    question_id = models.ForeignKey('Questionnaire', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer = models.CharField(max_length = 600)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.answer

class Test(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey('registration.MyUser')
    created_at = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    closed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class UserAnswer(models.Model):
    test_id = models.ForeignKey('Test')
    question = models.ForeignKey('Questionnaire')
    answer = models.ForeignKey('Answers')
```

views.py:

```
def AnswerChoiceSelect(request):
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    if request.method == "POST":
        answer_form = QuestionChoices(request.POST)
        if answer_form.is_valid():
            print("working")
        else:
            print('Non Valid form')
    else:
        answer_form = QuestionChoices(request.user)
    return render(request,'question_template.html',
                            {'answer_form':answer_form })
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from registration.models import MyUser
from .models import Questionnaire, Answers, Test, UserAnswer
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()


class QuestionChoices(forms.Form):

    question_choice = forms.ModelChoiceField(widget=forms.RadioSelect, queryset=None)

    def __init__(self,questionnaire, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QuestionChoices, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        current_question = Questionnaire.objects.get(id = question_id)
        self.fields['question_choice'].queryset = Answers.objects.filter(question_id = Current_question.id)
```

Comment: You have to use inline formset factory.

Comment: or try this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/ It gives steps for a poll app.

Comment: awsome I will give it a look thx you ;)